# htaccess redirect http to https keeping submains

Tags: .htaccess

i've been trying to work with the htaccess and went to many websites and no luck.

i need help with the following if user type the following:

1. testingsite.com -> https://www.testingsite.com
2. http//:testingsite.com -> https://www.testingsite.com
3. http//:sub.testingsite.com -> https://sub.testingsite.com

```html
RewriteEngine On

#Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This checks if the URL has:

1. SSL enabled (HTTPs)
2. If `www` is not present.

If either of those match, it will then force HTTPs and `www` onto the URL. I've set this using a `R=301` redirection, which is permanent. For testing purposes I advise you change this to `R=302` as this is temporary.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.